# C# Graphics DrawString VerticalDirection start from the bottom

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008

I need to write using Graphics.DrawString in a print Document method , a string with vertical direction and I have a limitation on the string width , the problem is that the string is writen from left to right and I need that the first line be on the right I'm using the method below

```
SizeF s = e.Graphics.MeasureString(str1, po.defaultF,la1, StringFormat.GenericTypographic);
RectangleF rec=new RectangleF();
StringFormat strF=new StringFormat();
strF.FormatFlags=StringFormatFlags.DirectionVertical;
rec.Height=s.Width+15;
rec.Width=s.Height+5;
rec.X =0;
rec.Y=0;
e.Graphics.DrawString(str1, po.defaultF, Brushes.Black, rec, strF);
```

Comment: Use Graphics.RotateTransform().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use RotateTransform(90) and without using the StringFormatFlags.DirectionVertical
here is the peace of code:

```
Rectangle rec = new Rectangle();
rec.Height = 2 * po.medF.Height;
rec.Width=100;
rec.X = 0;
rec.Y = 0;
SizeF s;
String str = "your Text";
StringFormat strf = new StringFormat();
strf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;    
rec.X = 0;
rec.Y = 0;
e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(X1, Y1);
e.Graphics.RotateTransform(90);
e.Graphics.DrawString(str, po.medF, Brushes.Black, rec, strf);
e.Graphics.ResetTransform();
```

Comment: I don't know why this answer was down voted. It's pricipally correct. The TranslateTransform/RotateTransform/DrawString/ResetTransform is the only feasible solution to the problem I found and tested. Up-voting.

Comment: I think it has been down voted because it is completely un-understandable. "I have a limitation on the string width" what does that mean? " I need that the first line be on the right" what does that mean?

Answer (score 4):

As Hans' commented, the `RotateTransform` can be used to flip the string around:

```
strF.Alignment = StringAlignment.Far;
e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(rec.Right, rec.Bottom);
e.Graphics.RotateTransform(180);
e.Graphics.DrawString(str1, po.defaultF, Brushes.Black, rec, strF);
```

The [TranslateTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a1d65f4.aspx) changes the origin of your coordinate system to the bottom right corner of your `rec` rectangle, then the `RotateTransform` flips it 180 degrees, and then the alignment of the string is changed to Far to place the string into the same place your original string was drawing.

Comment: This solution don't resolve my problem since the first line still at the left and then the second line to the right what I need isn't to change the text direction the problem is that when the text is split to fit to the rectangle the first line is at the left and i need it on the right

Comment: @Mario You might have to edit your question with an image.  I'm having a hard time envisioning how you are trying to display the text.

Comment: 180? I expected it to be 90 or 270.

Comment: @Bitterblue Per the OP's post, they were already using `FormatFlags=StringFormatFlags.DirectionVertical;`, so the 180 is to just flip that around the other direction.  I struggled with what the question was trying to ask.

Comment: It works. Full stop. One might need to add e.Graphics.ResetTransform() to be able to continue with unaffected drawing space.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at this example:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287525%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

It should do exactly what you're asking.

EDIT:

Possibly stupid way of drawing from right to left:

```
SizeF s = e.Graphics.MeasureString(str1, po.defaultF,la1, 
StringFormat.GenericTypographic);
RectangleF rec=new RectangleF();
StringFormat strF=new StringFormat();
strF.FormatFlags=StringFormatFlags.DirectionVertical;
rec.Height=s.Width+15;
rec.Width=s.Height+5;
rec.X =0;
rec.Y=0;
string[] strRightToLeft = str1.Split('\n');
Array.Reverse(strRightToLeft);
e.Graphics.DrawString(String.Concat(str1), po.defaultF, Brushes.Black, rec, strF);
```

Comment: this is what I'm using but the problem is when I have multi lines the first line will be on the left and i need it on the right

Comment: I'm not sure it will work, but have you tried `strF.Alignment = StringAlignment.Far;`?

Comment: It may not be easily possible. I have a workaround, but there may be a better way. I'll post it anyway.

Comment: I wanted to try this method but the string str1 don't contain '\n' and after the function MeasureString str1 don't change so this will not resolve the problem since the multi line is created by the function DrawString it self

Comment: In that case, I don't think there is any obvious way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I adapted the code snippet from @LarsTech's answer and it worked for me as below:

```cs
strF = new StringFormat();
strF.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near;
strF.FormatFlags = StringFormatFlags.DirectionVertical | StringFormatFlags.DirectionRightToLeft;
e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(rec.Right, rec.Bottom);
e.Graphics.RotateTransform(180);
e.Graphics.DrawString(str1, po.defaultF, Brushes.Black, rec, strF);
```

The text will be drawn as if it is written from bottom to top, left-aligned.